# h5py can't read strings written by julia HDF5

Tags: python, julia, hdf5, h5py

I'm able to read and write strings only from julia into HDF5 without problem:

```
julia> h5write("test.h5", "stringdset", "some string")
0

julia> h5read("test.h5", "stringdset")
"some string"
```

Strings that are written by h5py can be read by both Python and Julia:

```
In [27]: with h5py.File("testpy.h5", "a") as f:
    ...:     f["testdset"] = "works from python"


In [29]: with h5py.File("testpy.h5", "a") as f:
    ...:     print(f["testdset"][()])

works from python

julia> h5read("testpy.h5", "testdset")
"works from python"
```

But when I write a string from Julia, h5py can't find a conversion to read it:

```
with h5py.File("test.h5") as f:
   ...:     f["stringdset"][()]
   ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-cc416a9c995d> in <module>
      1 with h5py.File("test.h5") as f:
----> 2     f["stringdset"][()]
      3

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

~/envs/data/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py in __getitem__(self, args)
    544             arr = numpy.ndarray(selection.mshape, dtype=new_dtype)
    545             for mspace, fspace in selection:
--> 546                 self.id.read(mspace, fspace, arr, mtype)
    547             if len(names) == 1:
    548                 arr = arr[names[0]]

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5d.pyx in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.read()

h5py/_proxy.pyx in h5py._proxy.dset_rw()

h5py/_proxy.pyx in h5py._proxy.H5PY_H5Dread()

OSError: Can't read data (no appropriate function for conversion path)
```

This might be related to variable length strings? h5py recognizes the dtype, but still can't read it in.

```
In [7]: f = h5py.File("test.h5")

In [13]: f["stringdset"]
Out[13]: <HDF5 dataset "stringdset": shape (), type "|S11">


In [8]: f["stringdset"].dtype
Out[8]: dtype('S11')
```

Is there some easy fix to this I have missed? Or is it something conservative h5py is doing with string encodings?

FYI here's my version info:

```
In [3]: print(h5py.version.info)
Summary of the h5py configuration
---------------------------------

h5py    2.9.0
HDF5    1.10.4
Python  3.7.3 (default, Jun 19 2019, 07:38:49)
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)]
sys.platform    darwin
sys.maxsize     9223372036854775807
numpy   1.16.2
```